# i am trying to show the ad that i created in admob using its ID

Tags: flutter, dart

its totally working fine with TestAdId but when i enter my own AdUnitID it gives the below error.
it will be appreciated to make the ads appear in between the posts inside the listview...
everything is set up properly the only problem is using the real adUnitId.
i am stuck in this for 4 days your help will be appreciated.

The Error

```
Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(load_failed_ad, cannot reload a failed ad, id=71281197, null))


**code**
class Car extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CarState createState() => _CarState();
}

class _CarState extends State<Car> {
  static String adId = 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxx2680942917/5470xxxxxx';
  String appId = 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxx2680942917~6128xxxxxx';
  MobileAdTargetingInfo targetingInfo;
  BannerAd myBanner;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: appId);
    myBanner = createBannerAd()..load();
    MobileAdTargetingInfo(
      keywords: <String>['flutterio', 'beautiful apps'],
      contentUrl: 'https://flutter.io',
      childDirected: false,
      //testDevices: <String>[],
    );
  }

  BannerAd createBannerAd() {
    return BannerAd(
      adUnitId: adId,
      size: AdSize.fullBanner,
      targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
      listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
        print("BannerAd event $event");
      },
    );
  }

  showBanner() {
    myBanner ??= createBannerAd();
    myBanner
      ..load()
      ..show(
        // Positions the banner ad 60 pixels from the bottom of the screen
        anchorOffset: 0.0,
        // Positions the banner ad 10 pixels from the center of the screen to the right
        horizontalCenterOffset: 0.0,
        // Banner Position
        // anchorType: AnchorType.bottom,
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(
    BuildContext context,
  ) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal[50],
        body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('car').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.data == null)
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.teal),
                ),
              );

            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        //AD
                        (showBanner() != null) ? showBanner() : Container(),
                       ...
```